# Not able to run podman/docker hello-world in ubuntu WSL, gets OCI not found

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, podman

I'm trying to run a hello-world with podman/docker but gets the following error about cannot open sd-bus... don't know what it is or what OCI is. My setup that I need to use is: running podman that is installed on ubuntu in WSL.

```
WARN[0004] Failed to add conmon to systemd sandbox cgroup: dial unix /run/systemd/private: connect: no such file or directory
Error: cannot open sd-bus: No such file or directory: OCI not found
```

Comment: Please provide some details on how you installed podman, what research you've done so far, and what you've found from that research that hasn't worked.

Comment: There is a feature request for  [podman Windows WSL support](https://github.com/containers/podman/issues/3288) in the Podman github project.

Comment: @ErikSjölund so you're saying podman doesn't support my setup as described above?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know. I just thought the feature request had some similarities. A tip: the Podman developers usually answer questions pretty fast here: https://github.com/containers/podman/discussions  https://lists.podman.io/archives/list/podman@lists.podman.io/

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds I fresh-installed Fedora 35–WSL2, `dnf`ed `podman`, did `podman run registry.fedoraproject.org/fedora:latest echo hello`, and got that. “Research.” What research could you do if you don’t know anything about that, other than coming to SO and asking?

Comment: Typically I would hope for at least a cursory Google (or your search engine of choice) search for something like "WSL" "podman".  The first couple of links are "how to's" that sound like they might solve your problem.  No guarantees, but if you haven't done any  research yourself, it's not really fair of you to expect others to do it for you, is it?  Not trying to be critical here; just trying to help you [ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) here on Stack Overflow (see -- *"Search and research"*).